# angular 2 project on server is not working since i updated the database

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

hi I am working on Angular 2 project which was previously working properly on localhost as well as the server but since when I updated the data new database it shows error in fetching data from the database  the error is as follow

**Error**

> ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '525' of type 'number'. NgFor only supports binding
>   to…, …}
>
> message:"Cannot find a differ supporting object '525' of type
>   'number'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."
>   name:"Error"

Here is the code of service that is fetching data from the database

```
campaign() {
    const key = localStorage.getItem('currentUser'); 
    return this.http.post(this.baseurl + 'campaign/', JSON.stringify({  keys: key}))
    .map((response: Response) => response.json()); 
  }
```

Comment: post code of your service which is fetching data and component calling that service and html file, or set up plunker or stackblitz.com.

Comment: Could you give us an example of your response? It's probably not an Array